# How to add Intro/Home/Title screen to iOS Game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Got a simple game up and running but as soon as the game opens it starts.

I realize should have already made the home screen before the rest, but none the less I am here now.

So basically I am asking how do I go about adding a menu so that when the game boots it stops at the menu first therefor enabling the option to press start. I have used a combination of apps and google to get where I am now. So my programming is limited, but I am not stupid.

I know I need to make the document representing the menu, add the images to it, and then have the start button call the rest of the app when it is pressed. But thats it!

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is your game based on UIKit or other games frameworks? If you're using Storyboards, then you can just add a view controller ahead of your current-first view controller, and set it as default. If not, you should tell us on what framework does your game rely on, because the answer will depend on it.

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for the reply. No story boards. =/ its built in Cocos 2d, and has quite a few different frameworks. I am not sure which it relies on mostly so I will list them all. QuartzCore, OpenGLES, OpenAL, AudioToolbox,AVFoundation, UIKit, Foundation,CoreGraphics, and GameKit. LOL. Sorry, for being a noob. But thank you so much for helping. Its ready to be submitted but really want to get a menu on it for obvious purposes.

Comment: I've added the "cocos2d-iphone" tag in your question to make people who know this framework come and give a better answer. Meanwhile, have a look at this other SO topic, which seems fairly close to what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286408/how-do-i-add-a-menu-to-an-already-made-game-in-cocos2d-and-box2d-for-iphone

Comment: Thanks! I did search much before posting, but this seems remarkably similar so I will work my way through it and see if I can get it to work! :)

Comment: I have been attempting to work through the link you gave, with not much luck. Some of the functions are deprecated and attempting to work through them with google has not yielded much fruit either! =/

Comment: I must admit I won't be able to help you more, as I don't use Cocos2d, but there are plenty of resources out there. To begin with, you can check out Ray Wenderlich's tutorials, they're quite up-to-date and take you from the beginning of the project to a working (simple) game: http://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=cocos2d&cof=FORID%3A10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cocos2d games are defined by scenes, layers and sprites. So I suggest thinking about how you would  like to break your game down. Think about main menu scene, game scene, game over scene, leaderboard scene, and so on. Then think about how you want to link these scenes together. Which will lead to which and what conditions need to be met before such transition occurs.

Once you have a high level idea of how you want to break it down take a look at what you  have. You most likely have an initial scene class that's called from your AppDelegate as your first scene.

So create a new scene, add your main menu items (like play, choose level, options etc) and have that scene become your initial scene called from AppDelegate.

For more detail on how to do this give this a read "[Create a simple menu...](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/creating-a-simple-menu-with-scene-transition-in-cocos2d/)"
 I know that tutorial is a bit outdated and may not work as intended with cocos2d v3. But reading it will give you a better understanding of how cocos2d works and how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using sprite kit, create another subclass of SKScene, and use SKLabelNode(s) for the "menu items" and do

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     for(UITouch *t in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [t locationInNode:self];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(*labelNode.frame*, location)) {

            // do action 
        }
     }
 }
```

you can also do storyboard based items as discussed in comments

hope that helps